# Controller with suspend function causing netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlinx/coroutines/ThreadContextElement

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, micronaut, java-http-client

I am trying to create the simplest possible Controller suspend function which will call another endpoint. The learning purpose is to understand how to work with the Suspend function and Coroutine in Kotlin.

For that, I create a suspend function as an endpoint and it is calling another suspend function from a service layer that will use JDK HttpClient to call another endpoint.

Here is Controller

```
package com.tolearn.controller

import com.tolearn.service.DemoService
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Produces
import java.net.http.HttpResponse
import javax.inject.Inject

@Controller("/tolearn")
class DemoController {

    @Inject
    lateinit var demoService: DemoService

    @Get
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    suspend fun getOtherEndpointViaCoroutine(): HttpResponse<String> {

        return demoService.fetchUrl()
    }
}
```

The service

```
package com.tolearn.service

import java.net.URI
import java.net.http.HttpClient
import java.net.http.HttpRequest
import java.net.http.HttpResponse
import java.time.Duration
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
class DemoService {

    suspend fun fetchUrl(): HttpResponse<String> {

        val client: HttpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
                .followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.NEVER)
                .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20))
                .build()

        val request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create("http://localhost:3000/employees"))
                .build()

        val response = client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        return response.get()
    }

}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.4.10"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt") version "1.4.10"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version "1.4.10"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "6.1.0"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "1.2.0"
}

version = "0.1"
group = "com.tolearn"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.tolearn.*")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kotlin:micronaut-kotlin-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8:1.4.2")

    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
}


application {
    mainClass.set("com.tolearn.ApplicationKt")
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("11")
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }

}
```

I call the endpoint with

```
curl --location --request GET 'localhost:8080/tolearn'
```

And I get this error

```
C:\Users\Public\Java\jdk-11.0.9+11\bin\java.exe -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:54690,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:C:\Users\DEMETRC\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2020.2\groovyHotSwap\gragent.jar -javaagent:C:\Users\DEMETRC\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2020.2\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\DEMETRC\_c\to_learn\demo-coroutine\build\classes\kotlin\main;C:\Users\DEMETRC\_c\to_learn\demo-coroutine\build\tmp\kapt3\classes\main;C:\Users\DEMETRC\_c\to_learn\demo-coroutine\build\resources\main;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut\micronaut-validation\2.2.1\2b346cacc3e3c3ae08952e34add3fb335b99d5c9\micronaut-validation-2.2.1.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8\1.4.10\998caa30623f73223194a8b657abd2baec4880ea\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.4.10.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-reflect\1.4.10\e2b3c6695eee6085e606d96d685396dce23a3a06\kotlin-reflect-1.4.10.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut.kotlin\micronaut-kotlin-runtime\2.2.0\b8b24a7e5ea4d68afd6edc283f2b1f944bbf2cc7\micronaut-kotlin-runtime-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut\micronaut-http-client\2.2.1\f58e0b275df5a4c2fda59083a631a10efc51b038\micronaut-http-client-2.2.1.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut\micronaut-http-server-netty\2.2.1\53dc929dca3e3068638e6a22544a1fbd023fa06b\micronaut-http-server-netty-2.2.1.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut\micronaut-runtime\2.2.1\67b934a4fa0a2ccb8b98be40a05cdb297e5516b2\micronaut-runtime-2.2.1.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut\micronaut-inject\2.2.1\fa4267534151e925acd48339113555ab15222ae1\micronaut-inject-2.2.1.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\934c04d3cfef185a8008e7bf34331b79730a9d43\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut\micronaut-http\2.2.1\35fbf76299ba6d433f7bb18b11e5a1f7613c286e\micronaut-http-2.2.1.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.26\77100a62c2e6f04b53977b9f541044d7d722693d\slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\cb855558e6271b1b32e716d24cb85c7f583ce09e\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7\1.4.10\30e46450b0bb3dbf43898d2f461be4a942784780\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.4.10.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.4.10\ea29e063d2bbe695be13e9d044dcfb0c7add398e\kotlin-stdlib-1.4.10.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut\micronaut-http-client-core\2.2.1\f1153f5acb025c9f2330670054c07c94f75aa89c\micronaut-http-client-core-2.2.1.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut\micronaut-websocket\2.2.1\a0db7bc65c3c504f1908a35191cd4bc3eee3a597\micronaut-websocket-2.2.1.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-handler-proxy\4.1.54.Final\8fa9d18b09a8a79bf64e8bc1bd775cbd77277199\netty-handler-proxy-4.1.54.Final.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut\micronaut-http-server\2.2.1\21d341f2ee609d14acd481049de9206b0607683d\micronaut-http-server-2.2.1.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut\micronaut-http-netty\2.2.1\855a31775ec7c170282c5ad34177edd07247508b\micronaut-http-netty-2.2.1.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-codec-http\4.1.54.Final\70eb9509289d1cee549cf12bae71929d1a4a12c7\netty-codec-http-4.1.54.Final.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut\micronaut-aop\2.2.1\a8e591272fc3b5e0943f4ccc9ae53206445b5f46\micronaut-aop-2.2.1.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.reactivex.rxjava2\rxjava\2.2.10\18e9edc67e0abaa03713eeb9ca2cb0e30c859de4\rxjava-2.2.10.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.11.2\d4c1933a8d62db65c3d5a5cd809511e021a189c0\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.11.2.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.11.2\e6235e5eb3cf3edd2a95cd0dc96bc48aeb309e8a\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.11.2.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut\micronaut-core\2.2.1\c4e4f05efc2e97dbf7a8f4fe02ab89ad0acfc13\micronaut-core-2.2.1.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.yaml\snakeyaml\1.26\a78a8747147d2c5807683e76ec2b633e95c14fe9\snakeyaml-1.26.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.inject\javax.inject\1\6975da39a7040257bd51d21a231b76c915872d38\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.4.10\6229be3465805c99db1142ad75e6c6ddeac0b04c\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.4.10.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains\annotations\13.0\919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9\annotations-13.0.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-codec-socks\4.1.54.Final\8f8239e989e80cd470eaea90ee5746dbf24f5b8e\netty-codec-socks-4.1.54.Final.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-codec\4.1.54.Final\295680345b12a86c21fa7af5d9a77e0e0fcff46a\netty-codec-4.1.54.Final.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-transport\4.1.54.Final\ddb9a255819b87b8812932d1d1001f4d9dc7f89e\netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-buffer\4.1.54.Final\15c513ef8a2e56e88d3736752ea10eae758f47d8\netty-buffer-4.1.54.Final.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-common\4.1.54.Final\8c330383cda87204ab38e7401ab0f56c0d43b799\netty-common-4.1.54.Final.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut\micronaut-router\2.2.1\f5f0128e8741af1a88358496a72a2170fe112f73\micronaut-router-2.2.1.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micronaut\micronaut-buffer-netty\2.2.1\503578d211959e86863a451d698292cc626cd0d3\micronaut-buffer-netty-2.2.1.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-codec-http2\4.1.54.Final\327a4ae62b0a41cdf02f610f06eb353f10c17ef8\netty-codec-http2-4.1.54.Final.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-handler\4.1.54.Final\e83dfe8ebe3622d2cd5cce8532a9ca49cad51e9\netty-handler-4.1.54.Final.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.reactivestreams\reactive-streams\1.0.3\d9fb7a7926ffa635b3dcaa5049fb2bfa25b3e7d0\reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.spotbugs\spotbugs-annotations\4.0.3\755cc5d84d32b31beeaf8597181f0fc4eac98e16\spotbugs-annotations-4.0.3.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-resolver\4.1.54.Final\7eed781e7531b990f8360e1a5010b53ca73878f5\netty-resolver-4.1.54.Final.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.code.findbugs\jsr305\3.0.2\25ea2e8b0c338a877313bd4672d3fe056ea78f0d\jsr305-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.module\jackson-module-kotlin\2.11.3\ad8d29545c5ab0cdd6d49ee38f7ece8d9f772815\jackson-module-kotlin-2.11.3.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\7c4f3c474fb2c041d8028740440937705ebb473a\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.typesafe\config\1.4.1\19058a07624a87f90d129af7cd9c68bee94535a9\config-1.4.1.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.11.3\4f7b27416934dc929bb6c2d2c5fe521829e6a4ec\jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\2.11.3\25d4e9c777e7a8805c4a000a8629d3009c779c9b\jackson-annotations-2.11.3.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-core\1.2.3\864344400c3d4d92dfeb0a305dc87d953677c03c\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\DEMETRC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.11.3\c2351800432bdbdd8284c3f5a7f0782a352aa84a\jackson-core-2.11.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.tolearn.ApplicationKt
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:54690', transport: 'socket'
19:25:39.423 [main] INFO  io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Startup completed in 5074ms. Server Running: http://localhost:8080
19:26:14.218 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] ERROR i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Unexpected error occurred: kotlinx/coroutines/ThreadContextElement
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlinx/coroutines/ThreadContextElement
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at io.micronaut.http.bind.binders.CustomContinuation.<init>(ContinuationArgumentBinder.kt:59)
    at io.micronaut.http.bind.binders.ContinuationArgumentBinder.bind(ContinuationArgumentBinder.kt:36)
    at io.micronaut.http.bind.binders.ContinuationArgumentBinder.bind(ContinuationArgumentBinder.kt:31)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.binding.RequestArgumentSatisfier.getValueForArgument(RequestArgumentSatisfier.java:129)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.NettyRequestArgumentSatisfier.getValueForArgument(NettyRequestArgumentSatisfier.java:57)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.binding.RequestArgumentSatisfier.fulfillArgumentRequirements(RequestArgumentSatisfier.java:86)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.handleRouteMatch(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:675)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.channelRead0(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:553)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.channelRead0(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:148)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsHandler.java:199)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsServerHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsServerHandler.java:121)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.channelRead(HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.java:64)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.flow.FlowControlHandler.dequeue(FlowControlHandler.java:200)
    at io.netty.handler.flow.FlowControlHandler.channelRead(FlowControlHandler.java:162)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlinx.coroutines.ThreadContextElement
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 78 common frames omitted
19:26:33.630 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] ERROR i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Unexpected error occurred: kotlinx/coroutines/ThreadContextElement
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlinx/coroutines/ThreadContextElement
    at io.micronaut.http.bind.binders.CustomContinuation.<init>(ContinuationArgumentBinder.kt:59)
    at io.micronaut.http.bind.binders.ContinuationArgumentBinder.bind(ContinuationArgumentBinder.kt:36)
    at io.micronaut.http.bind.binders.ContinuationArgumentBinder.bind(ContinuationArgumentBinder.kt:31)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.binding.RequestArgumentSatisfier.getValueForArgument(RequestArgumentSatisfier.java:129)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.NettyRequestArgumentSatisfier.getValueForArgument(NettyRequestArgumentSatisfier.java:57)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.binding.RequestArgumentSatisfier.fulfillArgumentRequirements(RequestArgumentSatisfier.java:86)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.handleRouteMatch(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:675)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.channelRead0(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:553)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.channelRead0(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:148)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsHandler.java:199)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsServerHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsServerHandler.java:121)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.channelRead(HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.java:64)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.flow.FlowControlHandler.dequeue(FlowControlHandler.java:200)
    at io.netty.handler.flow.FlowControlHandler.channelRead(FlowControlHandler.java:162)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I take out the suspended words then it works correctly. I mean it returns the content.

So my straight question: isn't possible to create a controller with suspending keyword in other to work as Coroutines? Does it sound strange a controller as suspend function?

Comment: In your `classpath` there is not the `kotlinx-coroutines-core` JAR.

Comment: @GeorgeLeung, thanks. I added the dependency with "implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2")". Do I have to do anything else in order to add this to my classpath?

Comment: I guess this may be solved with a re-import with IntelliJ. Or try running `.\gradlew.bat run` directly in command line.

Comment: @GeorgeLeung, it is fixed. Not sure why is working now. Kindly, write your last comment as answer so I can pick it up. If you can see my current issue with Coroutine in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65348268/kotlin-coroutine-scope-is-returnrunblocking-an-issue-if-used-in-controller-en I will be thanked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the snippet, one can infer that the application is run using IntelliJ.

This string:
`C:\Users\Public\Java\jdk-11.0.9+11\bin\java.exe -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:54690,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:C:\Users\DEMETRC\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2020.2\groovyHotSwap\gragent.jar -javaagent:C:\Users\DEMETRC\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2020.2\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "`... is the actual command run by IntelliJ.

The dependency `kotlinx-coroutines-core` is not listed in the `classpath`, so the class `ThreadContextElement` cannot be found. This dependency is listed `build.gradle`, but for some reason IntelliJ does not recognize it.

---

This mismatch may be caused by an edit to `build.gradle` not followed by a [reload](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-projects.html#gradle_refresh_project). So IntelliJ is stuck with the old list of dependencies.

If a refresh does not solve the problem, one can try running the main class with gradle directly, i.e. `./gradlew run` on Mac and Linux.